# MS Access Select Query If / Then with user input

Tags: ms-access

I have a basic select query pulling results, but what I want to do is take the results from one column, in this case it would contain "student", and have the query auto populate the last column with a code.  So something like if column x contains "student" then place 12345-ab, if it doesn't contain "student" than place 12345-abc.  In both cases I want to be able to specify one last part of that code through user input.  So a person would have to enter lets say "05", then the outputs would be 12345-ab-05, or 12345-abc-05.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Matthew

Comment: @ryanwildry I'm not sure where to begin at this point, I'm getting back into heavy Excel and Access work.  If there is a solution, we can use the same thinking with other scenarios.

Comment: Here's the first thing I would look at it. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3. Also, it sounds like you probably want a form to gather the input for the last bit of the string you are appending on for the SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look, and see what I can come up with.

Comment: =IIf([MEMBER_TYPE] Like "student","152513-assoc-NMS-",IIf([MEMBER_TYPE] Not Like "student","152513-assoc-NM-"))   The query brings back no results?  The other part would be to enter text before the query to add on to the end of the code we are using for student and non-student.

Comment: I also tried this:  =IIf([MEMBER_TYPE]="regular student member","152513-ACS-NMS-",IIf([MEMBER_TYPE]="regular member","152513-ACS-NM-"))

Comment: If "student" is not the exact value of `MEMBER_TYPE`, but you want all with the part "student" in it, you need asteriks `* ` at start and end `MEMBER_TYPE LIKE "*student*"`.

Comment: I still get no results when I run the query whether I use like with * or = with the exact phrase to look for.

Comment: SELECT ACS_Member_List_ALL.ID, ACS_Member_List_ALL.CST_KEY, ACS_Member_List_ALL    FROM ACS_Member_List_ALL
WHERE (((ACS_Member_List_ALL.PAYMENT_STATUS_CD)<>"D" And (ACS_Member_List_ALL.PAYMENT_STATUS_CD)<>"UD") AND ((ACS_Member_List_ALL.[Source Code])=IIf([MEMBER_TYPE] Like "*student*","152513-assoc-NMS-",IIf([MEMBER_TYPE] Not Like "*student*","152513-assoc-NM-"))) AND ((Year([ORIG_JOIN_DATE])*"12"+DatePart("m",[ORIG_JOIN_DATE]))=Year(Date())*"12"+DatePart("m",Date())-"1"))
ORDER BY ACS_Member_List_ALL.PRIMART_ADDESS_TYPE DESC , ACS_Member_List_ALL.HM_ADDR_1 DESC;

Comment: That is part of the query, the rest is just returning values from different rows.  The last part is where I am trying to make it work.

Comment: Please add the query to your question and format it.

Comment: You said you want to autopopulate a field with the `IIf` statement, but you use it as condition in `WHERE`clause. Explain! Additional you can delete the second `IIf`, because it's useless. The `Else` part of the first `IIf` only gets computed, if `MEMBER_TYPE` is NOT "student". So use `IIf([MEMBER_TYPE] Like "student","152513-assoc-NMS-","152513-assoc-NM-")`.

Answer (score 0):

Open up VB editor and create a module.  Create a function with your "student" logic and pass it the value of your user input (from a form text box) to the function and the value of "column x).  Then create your string you want in the function and return it.  Call that function in your query.